# Proper ADFS Single Sign Out Cleanup and Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, windows-server-2012, adfs

**First, our environment:**

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- MVC 5

**The issue:**

We have configured ADFS for both single-sign-on and single-sign-out. Both sign-on and sign-out are working fully. However, we are a bit tentative about our implementation because the way that we have *sign-out* implemented appears to be significantly different from what any documentation seems to describe.

**The question:**

Is the way we have this wired correct? Or is the fact that it's working this way just luck, and it's actually supposed to work some other way?

**How we have this working:**

Here is, at a high level, how we have things wired:

1. RP (relying party) submits to ADFS a `wsignoutcleanup1.0` request along with a wreply. Something like: `GET /adfs/ls/?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0&wreply=https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44300%2fAccount%2fLoggedOut HTTP/1.1`
2. ADFS responds 200 with a response body that contains the following:

   - A javascript redirect to the wreply issued in step one. `window.onload = function() { document.location = decodeURIComponent('https%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a44300%2fAccount%2fLoggedOut') }`
   - An iframe issuing one wsignoutcleanup1.0 for each RP. Something like: `<iframe style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px;" src="https://localhost:44300/Claims/FederationResult?wa=wsignoutcleanup1.0" id="signoutFrame" class="signoutFrame"></iframe>`
   - An iframe issuing a wsignout1.0 for the IP.
     `<iframe style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px;" src="https://localdevsts:44301/Home/Index/?wa=wsignout1.0" id="signoutFrame" class="signoutFrame"></iframe>`
   - The javascript effectively redirects us to the wreply we originally specified, and the iframes effectively sign us out of the IP as well as notify any other RPs to sign out.

**Our Specific Concern:**

Our solution is initiating the sign-out process by issuing a `wsignoutcleanup1.0` request. This is contrary to all documentation, which states to start the process with a `wsignout1.0` request.

**References:**

There is a lot more out there than what I'm listing here, but these are a few that my team kept coming back to (for better or worse).

- MSDN on WIF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377151.aspx
- TechNet on Sign-Out: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1439.ad-fs-how-to-invoke-a-ws-federation-sign-out.aspx
- Signout using API: http://www.stevesdevbox.com/Blogs/Writing-an-MVC-Security-Token-Service-for-Development
- ADFS lifecycle including cleanup: http://devproconnections.com/development/implementing-single-sign-and-sign-out-aspnet-apps

Any constructive responses to our question is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your specific details (the iframe with wsignout1.0) are new to me. Which no longer surprises me. And it is not correct indeed. It should only return wsignoutcleanup1.0.

Probably you'd better ask for signout with wsignout1.0, the fancy things have a tendency to be less stable... I used to do it too. But I stopped doing it.

Now to the next question: is it better than the standard or not? Microsoft has changed this often over time. There are disadvantages (each time different behavior) and advantages (it allows multiple, simultaneous, IdP logon sessions. Arguably heresy in SingleSignOn???)